# Error in solving symbolic inequalities using Matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, symbolic-computation

I am new to Matlab. I am trying to use `solve`:

```
syms x y
S = solve(x^2 + y^2 + x*y < 1, x > 0, y > 0, [x, y]);

solx = S.x
soly = S.y
```

but Matlab returns:

---

> Warning: 5 equations in 2 variables.
>
> In C:\Program 
>   Files\MATLAB\R2012a\toolbox\symbolic\symbolic\symengine.p>symengine at 54
>
> In mupadengine.mupadengine>mupadengine.evalin at 97
>
> In mupadengine.mupadengine>mupadengine.feval at 150
>
> In solve at 160
>
> Warning: Explicit solution could not be found. 
>   > In solve at 169
>
> Comma separated list expansion has cell syntax for an array that
>   is not a cell.
>
> Error in sym/subsref (line 1575)
>
> [inds{k},refs{k}] = privformat(inds{k});

---

Could anyone tell me how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do, if possible, is use a newer version of Matlab. The Symbolic Math toolbox has seen a lot of updates in recent years.

I'm using R2015a so I can't test your case exactly. Here are a few things you can try, however. First, use [`assumptions`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2012a/toolbox/symbolic/brvhfqp-1.html) (link to R2012a archived documentation). Second, I think your error is caused by solving for the vector `[x y]`, rather than the distinct variables, `x` and `y`. When using an old version of Matlab make sure to look at the archived online documentation for your version or use `help` and `doc` in your Command Window (what Google shows you will be for the current version only): [the archived documentation for `solve` in R2012a](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2012a/toolbox/symbolic/solve.html).

Here are those changes applied to your example:

```
syms x y;
assume(x > 0);
assume(y > 0);
S = solve(x^2 + y^2 + x*y < 1, x, y)
```

This still returns warnings:

> Warning: The solutions are parameterized by the symbols: u, v. To include 
>   parameters and conditions in the solution, specify the 'ReturnConditions' option. 
>   > In **solve>warnIfParams** (line 510)
>      In **solve** (line 360) 
>   Warning: The solutions are valid under the following conditions: 4*v^2 < u & u < 4 & 0 < v. To include parameters and conditions in the solution, specify the 'ReturnConditions' option. 
>   > In **solve>warnIfParams** (line 517)
>      In **solve** (line 360)

```
S = 

    x: [1x1 sym]
    y: [1x1 sym]
```

but also yields

```
(- 3*v^2 + u)^(1/2)/2 - v/2
```

for `S.x` and `v` for `S.y`